# Microsoft SQL query to view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sccm

I have this complex query that i want to turn into a view.

This query comes from https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/3e84b01b7d52b4ca7807 and i want to save it in a view or even as a table if possible.
`

```
/*##=============================================*/
/*## QUERY BODY                                  */
/*##=============================================*/
/* #region QueryBody */

/* Testing variables !! Need to be commented for Production !! */
-- DECLARE @UserSIDs              AS NVARCHAR(10)  = 'Disabled';
-- DECLARE @CollectionID          AS NVARCHAR(10)  = 'SMS00001';
-- DECLARE @Locale                AS INT           = 2;
-- DECLARE @Categories            AS NVARCHAR(250) = 'Tools';
-- DECLARE @Compliant             AS INT           = 0;
-- DECLARE @Targeted              AS INT           = 1;
-- DECLARE @Superseded            AS INT           = 0;
-- DECLARE @ArticleID             AS NVARCHAR(10)  = '';
-- DECLARE @ExcludeArticleIDs     AS NVARCHAR(250) = '';

/* Variable declaration */
DECLARE @LCID                  AS INT = dbo.fn_LShortNameToLCID(@Locale);
DECLARE @HelperFunctionExists  AS INT = 0;

/* Perform cleanup */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MaintenanceInfo', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MaintenanceInfo;

/* Check for helper function */
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[ufn_CM_GetNextMaintenanceWindow]') IS NOT NULL
    SET @HelperFunctionExists = 1;

/* Initialize HealthState descriptor table */
DECLARE @HealthState TABLE (
    BitMask     INT
    , StateName NVARCHAR(250)
)

/* Populate HealthState table */
INSERT INTO @HealthState (BitMask, StateName)
VALUES
    ('0',     'Healthy')
    , ('1',   'Unmanaged')
    , ('2',   'Inactive')
    , ('4',   'Health Evaluation Failed')
    , ('8',   'Pending Restart')
    , ('16',  'Update Scan Failed')
    , ('32',  'Update Scan Late')
    , ('64',  'No Maintenance Window')
    , ('128', 'Distant Maintenance Window')
    , ('256', 'Expired Maintenance Window')

/* Initialize ClientState descriptor table */
DECLARE @ClientState TABLE (
    BitMask     INT
    , StateName NVARCHAR(100)
)

/* Populate ClientState table */
INSERT INTO @ClientState (BitMask, StateName)
VALUES
    ('0', 'No Reboot')
    , ('1', 'Configuration Manager')
    , ('2', 'File Rename')
    , ('4', 'Windows Update')
    , ('8', 'Add or Remove Feature')

CREATE TABLE #MaintenanceInfo (
    ResourceID          INT
    , NextServiceWindow DATETIME
)

/* Get maintenance data */
IF @HelperFunctionExists = 1
    BEGIN
        WITH Maintenance_CTE AS (
            SELECT
                CollectionMembers.ResourceID
                , NextServiceWindow.Duration
                , NextServiceWindow.NextServiceWindow
                , RowNumber             = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ResourceID ORDER BY NextServiceWindow.NextServiceWindow)
                , ServiceWindowType
                , ServiceWindow.Enabled
            FROM vSMS_ServiceWindow AS ServiceWindow
                JOIN fn_rbac_FullCollectionMembership(@UserSIDs) AS CollectionMembers ON CollectionMembers.CollectionID = ServiceWindow.SiteID
                JOIN fn_rbac_Collection(@UserSIDs) AS Collections ON Collections.CollectionID = CollectionMembers.CollectionID
                    AND Collections.CollectionType = 2                           -- Device Collections
                CROSS APPLY ufn_CM_GetNextMaintenanceWindow(ServiceWindow.Schedules, ServiceWindow.RecurrenceType) AS NextServiceWindow
            WHERE  NextServiceWindow.NextServiceWindow IS NOT NULL
                AND ServiceWindowType <> 5 -- OSD Service
        )

        /* Populate MaintenanceInfo table and remove duplicates */
        INSERT INTO #MaintenanceInfo(ResourceID, NextServiceWindow)
        SELECT
            ResourceID
            , NextServiceWindow
        FROM Maintenance_CTE
        WHERE RowNumber = 1
    END

/* Get update data */
;
WITH UpdateInfo_CTE
AS (
    SELECT
        ResourceID      = Systems.ResourceID
        , Missing       = COUNT(*)
    FROM fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs) AS Systems
        JOIN fn_rbac_UpdateComplianceStatus(@UserSIDs) AS ComplianceStatus ON ComplianceStatus.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
            AND ComplianceStatus.Status = 2                                      -- Filter on 'Required' (0 = Unknown, 1 = NotRequired, 2 = Required, 3 = Installed)
        JOIN fn_rbac_ClientCollectionMembers(@UserSIDs) AS CollectionMembers ON CollectionMembers.ResourceID = ComplianceStatus.ResourceID
        JOIN fn_rbac_UpdateInfo(@LCID, @UserSIDs) AS UpdateCIs ON UpdateCIs.CI_ID = ComplianceStatus.CI_ID
            AND UpdateCIs.IsSuperseded IN (@Superseded)
            AND UpdateCIs.CIType_ID IN (1, 8)                                    -- Filter on 1 Software Updates, 8 Software Update Bundle (v_CITypes)
            AND UpdateCIs.ArticleID NOT IN (                                     -- Filter on ArticleID csv list
                SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ExcludeArticleIDs, ',')
            )
            AND UpdateCIs.Title NOT LIKE (                                       -- Filter Preview updates
                '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_Preview_of_%'
            )
        JOIN fn_rbac_CICategoryInfo_All(@LCID, @UserSIDs) AS CICategory ON CICategory.CI_ID = ComplianceStatus.CI_ID
            AND CICategory.CategoryTypeName = 'UpdateClassification'
            AND CICategory.CategoryInstanceName IN (@Categories)                 -- Filter on Selected Update Classification Categories
        LEFT JOIN fn_rbac_CITargetedMachines(@UserSIDs) AS Targeted ON Targeted.ResourceID = ComplianceStatus.ResourceID
            AND Targeted.CI_ID = ComplianceStatus.CI_ID
    WHERE CollectionMembers.CollectionID = @CollectionID
        AND IIF(Targeted.ResourceID IS NULL, 0, 1) IN (@Targeted)                -- Filter on 'Targeted' or 'NotTargeted'
        AND IIF(UpdateCIs.ArticleID = @ArticleID, 1, 0) = IIF(@ArticleID <> '', 1, 0)
    GROUP BY
        Systems.ResourceID
)

/* Get device info */
SELECT
    Systems.ResourceID

    /* Set Health states. You can find the coresponding values in the HealthState table above */
    , HealthStates      = (
        IIF(CombinedResources.IsClient != 1, POWER(1, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(
            ClientSummary.ClientStateDescription = 'Inactive/Pass'
            OR
            ClientSummary.ClientStateDescription = 'Inactive/Fail'
            OR
            ClientSummary.ClientStateDescription = 'Inactive/Unknown'
            , POWER(2, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(
            ClientSummary.ClientStateDescription = 'Active/Fail'
            OR
            ClientSummary.ClientStateDescription = 'Inactive/Fail'
            , POWER(4, 1), 0
        )
        +
        IIF(CombinedResources.ClientState != 0, POWER(8, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(UpdateScan.LastErrorCode != 0, POWER(16, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(UpdateScan.LastScanTime < (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), POWER(32, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(ISNULL(NextServiceWindow, 0) = 0 AND @HelperFunctionExists = 1, POWER(64, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(NextServiceWindow > (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), POWER(128, 1), 0)
        +
        IIF(NextServiceWindow < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), POWER(256, 1), 0)
    )
    , Missing           = ISNULL(Missing, (IIF(CombinedResources.IsClient = 1, 0, NULL)))
    , Device            = (
            IIF(
                SystemNames.Resource_Names0 IS NOT NULL, UPPER(SystemNames.Resource_Names0)
                , IIF(Systems.Full_Domain_Name0 IS NOT NULL, Systems.Name0 + '.' + Systems.Full_Domain_Name0, Systems.Name0)
            )
    )
    , OperatingSystem   = (
        CASE
            WHEN OperatingSystem.Caption0 != '' THEN
                CONCAT(
                    REPLACE(OperatingSystem.Caption0, 'Microsoft ', ''),          -- Remove 'Microsoft ' from OperatingSystem
                    REPLACE(OperatingSystem.CSDVersion0, 'Service Pack ', ' SP')  -- Replace 'Service Pack ' with ' SP' in OperatingSystem
                )
            ELSE (

            /* Workaround for systems not in GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM table */
                CASE
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Workstation 6.1%'    THEN 'Windows 7'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Workstation 6.2%'    THEN 'Windows 8'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Workstation 6.3%'    THEN 'Windows 8.1'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Workstation 10.0%'   THEN 'Windows 10'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Server 6.0'          THEN 'Windows Server 2008'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Server 6.1'          THEN 'Windows Server 2008R2'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Server 6.2'          THEN 'Windows Server 2012'
                    WHEN CombinedResources.DeviceOS LIKE '%Server 6.3'          THEN 'Windows Server 2012 R2'
                    WHEN Systems.Operating_System_Name_And0 LIKE '%Server 10%'  THEN (
                        CASE
                            WHEN CAST(REPLACE(Build01, '.', '') AS INTEGER) > 10017763 THEN 'Windows Server 2019'
                            ELSE 'Windows Server 2016'
                        END
                    )
                    ELSE Systems.Operating_System_Name_And0
                END
            )
        END
    )
    , LastBootTime      = (
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime0, 120)
    )
    , PendingRestart    = (
        CASE
            WHEN CombinedResources.IsClient      = 0
                OR CombinedResources.ClientState = 0
            THEN NULL
            ELSE (
                STUFF(
                    REPLACE(
                        (
                            SELECT '#!' + LTRIM(RTRIM(StateName)) AS [data()]
                            FROM @ClientState
                            WHERE BitMask & CombinedResources.ClientState <> 0
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                        ),
                        ' #!',', '
                    ),
                    1, 2, ''
                )
            )
        END
    )
    , ClientState       = (
        CASE CombinedResources.IsClient
            WHEN 1 THEN ClientSummary.ClientStateDescription
            ELSE 'Unmanaged'
        END
    )
    , ClientVersion     = CombinedResources.ClientVersion
    , LastUpdateScan    = (
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), UpdateScan.LastScanTime, 120)
    )
    , LastScanLocation  = NULLIF(UpdateScan.LastScanPackageLocation, '')
    , LastScanError     = NULLIF(UpdateScan.LastErrorCode, 0)
    , NextServiceWindow = IIF(CombinedResources.IsClient != 1, NULL, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), NextServiceWindow, 120))
FROM fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs) AS Systems
    JOIN fn_rbac_CombinedDeviceResources(@UserSIDs) AS CombinedResources ON CombinedResources.MachineID = Systems.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN fn_rbac_RA_System_ResourceNames(@UserSIDs) AS SystemNames ON SystemNames.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN fn_rbac_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM(@UserSIDs) AS OperatingSystem ON OperatingSystem.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN fn_rbac_CH_ClientSummary(@UserSIDs) AS ClientSummary ON ClientSummary.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN fn_rbac_UpdateScanStatus(@UserSIDs) AS UpdateScan ON UpdateScan.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN #MaintenanceInfo AS Maintenance ON Maintenance.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
    LEFT JOIN UpdateInfo_CTE AS UpdateInfo ON UpdateInfo.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
    JOIN fn_rbac_FullCollectionMembership(@UserSIDs) AS CollectionMembers ON CollectionMembers.ResourceID = Systems.ResourceID
WHERE CollectionMembers.CollectionID = @CollectionID
    AND (
        CASE                                                                     -- Compliant (0 = No, 1 = Yes, 2 = Unknown)
            WHEN Missing = 0 OR (Missing IS NULL AND Systems.Client0 = 1) THEN 1 -- Yes
            WHEN Missing > 0 AND Missing IS NOT NULL                      THEN 0 -- No
            ELSE 2                                                               -- Unknown
        END
    ) IN (@Compliant)

/* Perform cleanup */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MaintenanceInfo', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MaintenanceInfo;

/* #endregion */
/*##=============================================*/
/*## END QUERY BODY                              */
/*##=============================================*/
```

`
Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I have tried to look at the official Microsoft documentation but are still not able to convert the query to a view. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

As I am new to SQL language I am not sure where to start.

Comment: What you are asking doesn't really make sense. The above is a batch of SQL statements; that can't be a `VIEW` or a `TABLE`. Perhaps you want a (parametrised?) Stored Procedure? You need to elaborate on what you *actually* want to achieve here.

Comment: A view is a single SELECT statement query without any parameter or variable.  It cannot contains any procedural code DECLARE, SET, IF, DROP, INSERT, CREATE...

Answer (score 0):

So I agree with Larnu, that this probably doesn't make a ton of sense. But there are cases where one might want to be able to run multiple batches of queries / procedural code from an object that's as consumable as a view. I've done this once in a case where I needed to maximize my options for performance tuning without losing the consumability of the object. So for the sake of when it does make sense, this is something you could do:

1. Wrap your code in a stored procedure.
2. Use [`OPENQUERY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to call your procedure.
3. Wrap the `OPENQUERY()` call in a view.

Limitations with this methodology is it's rather static:

- You can't pass parameters to your stored procedure
- If you use temp tables in your stored procedure, then you need to use the `WITH RESULT SETS` clause to explicitly define the shape of your result set
- The procedure can only return one result set
- The SQL Server Engine puts a hard-coded cardinality estimate of 10,000 against `OPENQUERY()`. So in cases where your procedure returns a lot more rows (typically an order of magnitude or more) than 10,000, e.g. 1 million rows, then you may experience some performance issues with joining the wrapper view to other objects.

Example:

```
-- Step 1: Wrap the procedural code in a stored procedure 
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RunSomeCode
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Results (ID INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(100));

DECLARE @SomeVariable INT = 0;

WHILE (@SomeVariable < 5)
BEGIN
    SET @SomeVariable = @SomeVariable + 1;

    INSERT INTO #Results (ID, SomeValue)
    SELECT ID, SomeValue
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE ID = @SomeVariable
END

SELECT ID, SomeValue
FROM #Results;

END
GO

-- Step 2 & 3: Wrap an OPENQUERY() call to the procedure in a view.
CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeView
AS

SELECT ID, SomeValue
FROM OPENQUERY
(
'
    LocalServerName,
    EXEC dbo.RunSomeCode
    WITH RESULT SETS
    ((
        ID INT,
        SomeValue VARCHAR(100)
    ))
'
);
```

Voila, you can now execute the procedure by `SELECT`ing from the view:

```
SELECT ID, SomeValue
FROM dbo.SomeView;
```